# Client computers (W7) asking update PDFCreator printer drivers (2008R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, printing, drivers, shared-printers

For over 18 months it has been working. Suddenly, without any updates (server is not connected to the Internet) and nothing is being pushed to it, all client computers (over 100 of them) are asking to update printer drivers. Is there any known cause for that?

- All client computers are frozen with Deep Freeze, so it's surely not client-side related.
- The PDFCreator printer is at the same version, all configurations for the printer have not changed.
- The only thing is that clients are now asking to update the drivers.
- Obviously, users do not have the permissions to do that.

What I am really looking for is the cause for this so we can stop it from happening again.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the PDFCreator printer drivers come packaged with an application that automatically "phones home" from time to time to check for updates.  It phoned home, found an update, and is now prompting your users to install it.

To stop this from happening again, you would remove or reconfigure this application so it doesn't automatically check for (or prompt to install) updates.